# Navigationbar is nil

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

I set a navigationbar with the IB.
In my .h file I set the property and connected it with the navigationbar.

I also have a scrollview which i added programmatically.
I also added the navigationbar to the scrollview.

When i am running the programm it says, that the navigationbar is nil.

What could be the reason for that?

I set in my mainView a Navigationbar with the navigationcontroller.
There everything is fine. I can see the navigationbar. 
Than I want to switch from the mainview to another View.

```
 stg = [[SubtaskGenerator alloc]init];
    stg.subtaskObjectArray = array;
    [stg setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentModalViewController:stg animated:YES];
```

In the SubtaskGenerator.xib I also added a navigationbar and connected it to the property in SubtaskGenerator.h But this Navigationbar is nil

Comment: are you using `UINavigationController` to present your view controllers?

Comment: Yes, in my main view. From my mainview i am calling a presentModalViewController. It it is my navigationbar

Comment: You are talking about 2 navigation bars here, can you be more elaborate, provide some code etc, so that we can help.

Comment: When you say it is nil, can you see the navigation bar, or is it nil, when you try to NSLog it. Try changing the tint color of the SubtaskGenerator.xib and see if you are able to see a new navigation bar.

Comment: it is nil when I am NSLog it. In the .xib file I can see the navigationbar. But when i am running the code it is not there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I used only

```
stg = [[SubtaskGenerator alloc]init];
```

But to see the navigationbar i have to use

```
stg = [[SubtaskGenerator alloc]initWithNibName:@"SubtaskView" bundle:nil];
```